# Introductory Python task from the edX MIT class

Tags: python

I have recently started learning Python in the MIT class on edX, and I have been having some trouble with certain exercises. Here is one of them:

> Write a procedure called oddTuples, which takes a tuple as input, and
> returns a new tuple as output, where every other element of the input
> tuple is copied, starting with the first one. So if test is the tuple
> ('I', 'am', 'a', 'test', 'tuple'), then evaluating oddTuples on this
> input would return the tuple ('I', 'a', 'tuple').

The correct code, according to the lecture, is the following:

```
def oddTuples(aTup):
   '''
   aTup: a tuple
   
   returns: tuple, every other element of aTup.
   '''
    # a placeholder to gather our response
    rTup = ()
    index = 0
 
    # Idea: Iterate over the elements in aTup, counting by 2
    #  (every other element) and adding that element to
    #  the result
    while index < len(aTup):
        rTup += (aTup[index],)
        index += 2
 
    return rTup
```

However, I have tried to solve it myself in a different way with the following code:

```
def oddTuples(aTup):
    '''
   aTup: a tuple
   
   returns: tuple, every other element of aTup.
   '''
    # Your Code Here
    bTup=()
    i=0
    for i in (0,len(aTup)-1):
        if i%2==0:
            bTup=bTup+(aTup[i],)
            print(bTup)
        print(i)
        i+=1
    return bTup
```

My solution does not work and I am unable to understand why (I think it should do essentially the same thing as the code the tutors provide).

Comment: don't link the code, paste it here. it will save everybody's time.

Comment: show some `input - output` samples of your code.

Answer (score 3):

I just like to add that the pythonic solution for this problem uses slices with a stepwidth and is:

```
newTuple = oldTuple[::2]
```

`oldTuple[::2]` has the meaning: Get copy of oldtuple from start (value is omitted) to end (omitted) with a spepwidth of 2.

Comment: This is the idiomatic way to solve it, but the goal of the edX course is to teach programming, not to teach Python.  This exercise helps students become comfortable with loops.  Using extended slicing syntax doesn't help them here.

Answer (score 2):

I think I get the problem here.

In your for loop you specify two fixed values for `i`:

```
0
len(aTup)-1
```

Want you really want is the range of values from `0` to `len(aTup)-1`:

```
0
1
2
...
len(aTup)-1
```

In order to convert start and end values into all values in a range you need to use Python's `range` method:

```
for i in range(0,len(aTup)-1):
```

(Actually if you take a look into [range's documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range), you will find out there is a third parameter called `skip`. If you use it your function becomes kind of irrelevant :))

Comment: Thank you, people, I got it. Guess learning the syntax of Python will be harder than I thought

Answer (score 1):

Your code should read:

```
for i in range(0,len(aTup)):
# i=0, 1, 2 ..., len(aTup)-1.
```

rather than

```
for i in (0,len(aTup)-1):
# i=0 or i=len(aTup)-1.
```

Answer (score 1):

The lines `for i in (0,len(aTup)-1):` and `i+=1` aren't quite doing what you want.  As in other answers, you probably want `for i in range(0,len(aTup)-1):` (insert `range`), but you also want to remove `i+=1`, since the `for`-`in` construct sets the value of `i` to each of the items in the iterable in turn.

Answer (score 0):

Okay when running your code the output is the following:

```
('I', 'tuple')
```

This is because the problem in the code you wrote is the way you implement the for loop.
Instead of using:

```
for i in (0,len(aTup)-1):
```

You should change that to the following and your code will work:

```
for i in range(len(aTup)):
```

the range function basically creates a list of integers ranging from 0 to the length of your tuple - 1.

So your code should after editing it should look like:

```
def oddTuples(aTup):
    bTup=()
    for i in range(len(aTup)):
        if i%2==0:
            bTup=bTup+(aTup[i],)
    return bTup
```